# How to do a full screen background scroller component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, css-transitions

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a full screen landing page that has multiple backgrounds. I want the user to be able to scroll once and have the next background take up the entire screen. I also want to keep track of which section of the landing page the user is on similar to the position tracker on the right.

I'm trying to emulate the design on this page https://purpose.nike.com/
How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to achieve the wallpaper thing as nike as done you would have to add some transitions to make it look good. To achieve it add the background to each div you want and add following css.

   .bg{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw; }
    .bg_url1 { background: url1 }
    .bg_url2 { background: url2 }

    <div class="bg bg_url1"/>
    <div class="bg bg_url2"/>


add this to each wallpaper then you can combine it with javascript/jquery to add transitions to make it look good.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on jquery scrollify. Please see my example code where I make fullscreen div scrollable and console print (div position or index when finish scrolling).

```js
$(function() {
  $.scrollify({
    section : ".full_sc_div",
    after: function(index){
      console.log(index);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scrollify</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.19/jquery.scrollify.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="full_sc_div" style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
    <div class="full_sc_div" style="background-color: green;">div 2</div>
    <div class="full_sc_div" style="background-color: blue;">div 3</div>
    <div class="full_sc_div" style="background-color: white;">div 4</div>
    <div class="full_sc_div" style="background-color: black;">div 5</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try fullpage js : https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Section 1</div>
    <div class="section">
       <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Slide 2.1</div>
       <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Slide 2.2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="section">Section 3</div>
   <div class="section">Section 4</div>
</div>

<script>
    new fullpage('#fullpage', {
      sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The page you are talking about is nothing but multiple background placed under one another in different divisions

```
 <div>..Walpaper1..</div>
 <div>..Walpaper2..</div>
 <div>..Walpaper3..</div>
 <div>..Walpaper4..</div>
```

then provide Id's to all the dives and place all the content into the different div's associate do that div